# Highcharts iOS Swift : HIGauge.dial always return nil in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

when i try to change dial format using HIGauge, app get crash

below is my code :

```
    let speed = HIGauge()
    speed.name = "Speed"
    speed.data = [480]
    speed.tooltip = HITooltip()
    speed.tooltip.valueSuffix = " km/h"
    speed.dial.backgroundColor = HIColor(uiColor: UIColor.green)
```

app get crashed on 'speed.dial.backgroundColor'.
dial give nil value.

i have try to set

chart.styledMode = true

but still app get crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create an object `HIDial` and next set the color:

```
speed.dial = HIDial()
speed.dial.backgroundColor = HIColor(uiColor: UIColor.green)
```

Comment: thank u... it's working. It means we have to set new object for dial, right?